# VBA OneDrive Access

Tags: vba, path, onedrive

I have an excel file `tree.xlsm` which I have stored on my personal OneDrive subfolder `Tree`.

One of the requirements is for the VBA to display a photograph.

The folder has been shared with certain friends and so the path needs to be a URL so they can access it as well.

The code below is used to display the photograph.

```
sPath = Application.ActiveWorkbook.Path
Image1.Picture = LoadPicture(sPath & "\1001.jpg")
```

The VBA code crashes with Run-time error

> 75: Path/File access error.

If `sPath & "1001.jpg"` is copied into windows explorer the photograph is opened.

I think the error is caused by a OneDrive access rights issue.

Comment: The standard/default location of onedrive is `Environ$("USERPROFILE") & "\OneDrive"`. Try `sPath = Environ$("USERPROFILE") & "\OneDrive\Tree`

Comment: Thanks, this code does open the image, but the path it uses is the local drive and will not work for people with whom the file is shared. The code need to use a path like "https://d.docs.live.net/818ae8b59c14de19/Tree\1001.jpg" .  Note the photographs are in the same onedrive folder as the excel file.

Comment: Your friends need to log in onedrive.com, go to *Shared* (on the left hand side), where they will find your shared "*Tree*" folder. Right-click and choose *Add to my OneDrive*. This will make the folder available in **their** OneDrive and they can access it from their local OneDrive (desktop) as if it were their own folder.